# Running a copy of a .cshtml file gives a 404

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2013

I've created a copy(right-click Copy & Paste) of my Home page in a VS2013 ASP.NET MVC5 project and named it indexL10. When I try to run it, I get the following error:

> **Description:** HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> **Requested URL:** /Home/IndexL10

So, I'm guessing there's more to it than copying and pasting. I've tried googling around, but I've not found an answer, or search string that takes me to a page of a user with a similar problem. 
Does anyone have any ideas/suggestions? Thanks

Comment: You need a method in you controller named `IndexL10` that returns that view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*.cshtml files are not like *.aspx files. They're not directly exposed. The URL is translated by the framework into a route. That route points to a particular controller and a particular action in that controller, which is then called by the framework. The action returns an `ActionResult`, which in MVC is most typically satisfied via a `ViewResult`. Conventions in the framework come into play to look for a view to render with the same name as the action that was called, but this is not strictly required and can be overridden. Regardless, the view (your *.cshtml file) is rendered by Razor utilizing data provided by the action and returned as a response to the client.

Comment: I'll have to look into that, and the type of project I create. Thank you.