# Getting 404 while requesting an URL in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/)
tutorial on microsoft.com. It was all working fine till I reached to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/creating-a-connection-string)
page. I've copied the exact code for both Model and connection string but I'm getting the error of Resource not found.
[image]

As the version of VS used in the tutorial is different to mine(mine is VS 2013). I've tried every solution I could Google but no use.
I'm trying to solve this for more than 6 hours.

Editing the post as asked in the comments:

Code for Controller:

```
namespace MvcMovie.Controllers
{
    public class MoviesController : Controller
    {
        private MovieDBContext db = new MovieDBContext();

        // GET: /Movies/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Movies.ToList());
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Views/Movies/Index.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcMovie.Models.Movie>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Genre)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

RouteConfig.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MvcMovie
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Hello",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{name}/{id}"
       );
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to open: http://localhost:51033/Views/Movies/Index.cshtml
Also when I checked the AppData Folder, it's empty. So the code first DB is not created.

Comment: The error message is a 404. That has nothing to do with a connection string. It means the server couldn't find something the browser requested. Based on the URL in the error rmessage, it appears you're trying to request a view. But you shouldn't do that. You should write a request that routes to a controller action, the action will then be responsible for returning the view. You should go through some tutorials on [routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs) again until you understand it.

Comment: does this controller and view exist? paste your code please.

Comment: See in Global.asax.cs in application startup how routes are configured. Routes should call controller actions first then lookup for appropriate view.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller
Go through this step then try it again.

Comment: Why you are requesting /*.cshtml, that is not the way how ASP.NET MVC works. You should put /{controller}/{action} only, if that is the mapping you defined in your app start-up.

Comment: Thanks for the support people but I'm still stuck. Don't you think it could be because Index is not finding the Movie database to give it to the View?

Comment: Can you give me remote access (via team viewer) please to debug the problem?

Comment: @TanvirArjel I could happily, but sadly my internet connection is too slow for TeamViewer. But Thanks for asking.

Comment: Just to confirm, when you right click on your controller Index method and select go to view, is visual studio opening your Views/Movies/Index.cshtml file?

Comment: @PriyankPanchal Yes it is opening the View.

Comment: Ok, as @wannadream said, try removing .cshtml from your URL. So just put http://localhost:<yourport>/<youralias>/Movies and check if it opens the page you want. In MVC, the control goes to controller first and then it calls the view. Try also to put a break point on your Index method and check if it is hit when you go to the URL.

Comment: Include the url path in the question that you are requesting!

Comment: @TanvirArjel It is in the question. The path is shown in the error message.

Comment: @Waz I said it all in the first comment. Your URL doesn't match your route. You need to learn about routing. It has nothing to do with your database.

Comment: @mason I can't see any Local DB in my AppData folder.

Comment: @PriyankPanchal as you said in an earlier comment and the answer given by tanvirArjej worked fine. Thanks for the help bros.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running a copy of a .cshtml file gives a 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873840/running-a-copy-of-a-cshtml-file-gives-a-404)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are requesting wrong `Url` in wrong approach. `http://localhost:51033/Views/Movies/Index.cshtml` cannot be an `Url` in ASP.NET MVC. Please try with the following `Url`:

```
 http://localhost:51033/Movies/Index
```

Your problem should fix!

Answer (score 0):

After trying for so many solutions including the above answer I've came to the ultimate solution of my problem. I basically had two problems:

1. Invalid URL for MVC (although I did try http://localhost:51033/Movies for multiple times, but still the URL generated by the solution, which I was using was wrong).
2. My real problem was my connection string (which I was expecting). Apparently my LocalDB is not working for some reasons. So I used SQL Server installed on my system instead and it worked like a charm.

So, if anyone else faces this issue then they can try a connection string like the one below:

```
<add name="MovieDBContext"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MvcMovie;Integrated Security=True" />
```